# Find hidden parent element jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, hidden, display

How can I find parent element with `display: none` using jQuery?

```css
.hidden-one
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden-one"> <!-- FIND AND SHOW THIS ONE -->
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="deeper">
    <span class="start-here">Start here</span>
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to iterate all parents of `.start-here`:

```js
$('.start-here').parents().each(function() {
    
    if ($(this).css('display') === 'none')
    {
     $(this).show();
    }
   
});
```

```css
.hidden-one
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden-one"> <!-- FIND AND SHOW THIS ONE -->
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="deeper">
    <span class="start-here">Start here</span>
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```

This code also works for elements with `style="display: none"` attribute.

Answer (score -1):

**[Demo Link](https://jsfiddle.net/vijaypancholi2626/t9zsuwoy/7/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Find the first hidden parent element
    var hideparent_div = $('.start-here').closest('.hidden-one:hidden').first();

    // Show the hidden parent element
    hideparent_div.show();
});
```

```css
.hidden-one
{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="hidden-one"> <!-- FIND AND SHOW THIS ONE -->
  <div>...</div>
  <div>...</div>
  <div class="deeper">
    <span class="start-here">Start here</span>
  </div>
  <div>...</div>
</div>
```